# Can't retrieve 4 levels of nested entities with Algolia

Tags: symfony, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am using Algolia and I have the following entity hierarchy:

- Product
- ProductFormula ([1 - n] with Product)
- ProductDuration ([1 - n] with ProductFormula)
- ProductPricing ([1 - n] with ProductDuration)

I store them all on algolia and they are all effectively stored individually and linked as collections to their parent entities:

- From the `ProductDuration` objects I can see a `productPricings` array of objects
- From the `ProductFormula` objects I can see a `productDurations` array of `ProductDuration` objects and each of them contains (when existing) an array of `productPricings`
- **BUT**, from the `Product` object, I see the `ProductFormula` array, and then the `ProductDuration` array, but the `productPricings` is *always* `null`.

This was happening in the algolia explorer, so at first I thought that it would be a "preview" limitation. But when I make an actual query from my app (Symfony App, with the symfony bundle from algolia) I get the same problem.

I am trying to find a `maxnestinglevel` parameter but can't quite put my hands on it. Did I miss something out ?